# Horizontal d3 tree: how to have root starting at top left instead of middle y-axis?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've actually got a few questions about this tree but I'll ask them separately.

I've got a tree ([demo/code](http://jsbin.com/okUxAvE/1/edit?js,output)), which is obviously a stock d3 horizontal tree for the most part, save for a little tooltip I'm attaching to child nodes.

The question is, how can I have the tree expand from the top left of the container instead of radiating out from the middle of the y-axis? In other words, I want to end up with this:

```
START-----Parent 1-----Child 1
                  \
                   `---Child 2
```

etc., where START is at the top left of the SVG container. Note: the child nodes should thus expand downward and to the right.

I've been studying how x and y are working here but I just can't seem to figure out how to change this.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)?

Comment: Yes; isn't that the same type of thing as my example? It still starts at the center of the y-axis.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, misunderstood what you're trying to do. I suppose you could simply take the y coordinate of your root node and subtract half the height as a constant offset.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to work either. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that effect by modifying the x values at

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.x = /*yourValues*/; d.y = d.depth * 180; });
```

As you were probably aware of that much, the real key for your particular problem will be to provide each node with a value that relates to the number of nodes at its level (i.e. siblings). As the example you provided already gives a `depth` value to each node, you could always iterate through the nodes and tally those values, eventually yielding an array like:

```
node0 has 0 nodes before it in the same depth (depth 0)
node1 has 0 nodes before it in the same depth (depth 1)
node2 has 1 nodes before it in the same depth (depth 1)
```

**UPDATE** You can find the sibling values and achieve the desired effect by replacing the above `forEach` code with the following:

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) { //iterate through the nodes
    if(d.parent != null){ //if the node has a parent
        for(var i = 0; i < d.parent.children.length; i++){ //check parent children
            if(d.parent.children[i].name == d.name){ //find current node
                d.downset = i; //index is how far node must be moved down
            }
        }
        d.parentDownset = d.parent.downset; //must also account for parent downset
    }
    if(d.downset == null){ d.downset = 0; }
    if(d.parentDownset == null){ d.parentDownset = 0; }
    d.x = (d.downset * 40) + (d.parentDownset * 40) + 20;
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
});
```

Additionally, with the way that the children are named in your example, you could just parse out the number after the `.`

Take the `1` out of `Child 1.1`, otherwise return `0` for `Child 1` and `Child 2`

```
nodes.forEach(function(d,i) {
                              d.x = d.numberAfterPeriod * 40 + 20;
                              d.y = d.depth * 180;
                            });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That's the thing, though, I don't know how to get the "siblings" in this case.

Comment: @stephenhay Hm, I just updated my answer with a code that helps to get the sibling values. Although this may not be the most computationally efficient solution, it definitely gets the job done! Hope that helps.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, and you've certainly pointed me in the right direction. Also, your code comments are helpful in understanding your strategy. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Hope that it's at least a step in that direction - no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this using Angualr with D3js indented tree root starts at left top. it might be useful for future.

[image: D3js indented tree root start at top left]

Please find the github link here.
[https://github.com/AnandanSelvaganesan/angular-d3-tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8fUN.png)